# C# Threading/Async with callbacks? Ripping my hair out here

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, multithreading

I have had very few good experiences with threading. I have read sources but most full projects that utilize it well so are incredibly dense with threading being such a small part of it making it difficult to determine what is needed and what is not.

My project will mainly need to make HTTP POST requests for updates for an API, report back (through a callback?) and most likely put on a timer, or be able to be called multiple times on request.

The tutorials I have read have only covered basic stuff without reporting back and performing more operations on the new/newly calculated date. Even when they do, nearly all have used:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Which from what I have read is not a very good idea when you are performing it quote often.

So I guess my questions are as follows:

- Do I need a dispatcher of sorts?
- Is there a more in depth/reliable source for threading documentation and references on callbacks?
- Should I start off with two threads and store all my shared variables in a second thread that I can regularly check with from main, and update/alter with the secondary/other thread?

In regards to the schooling, this is not a school related project, it is a personal project involving the Eve Online API system. EVEMon's source is so compact, streamlined and developed that it is quite hard to distinguish between threads in its code. If anyone could give pointers on examining this it to would be helpful.

Comment: Don't you think that you teacher gives you a project to solve all this questions by yourself?

Comment: Not taking any programming classes until next semester. this is a personal project involving the Eve online API system.

Comment: I agree, disabling check for illegal cross thread calls is a bad idea, fix what is wrong, rather than disabling the thing that tells you it's wrong :)

Comment: What tech are you planning to use for the UI? WinForms or WPF/Silverlight? As it makes a difference to use Control.Invoke for winforms, and the Dispatcher for WPF/Silverlight

Comment: @Matt Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls that the op talks about is a winforms-property so that would imply winforms

Comment: It is a winforms application. and It would be handy if I could request the page, get the response, deserialize the XML and pass the deserialized data to a callback on the main thread and finish up the proccessing there.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph Albahari has a good set of [articles](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) on threading, and I also found Jon Skeet's [articles](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) very good.

There are many ways in .net to utilise threading, be warned however, it's also very easy to get it wrong :)

I personally prefer to use [reactive extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) which lets you convert the typical async pattern into an observable, and it also handles the ui thread marshalling for you.

e.g.

```
var wr = WebRequest.Create("http://someurl");

var o = Observable
    .FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(wr.BeginGetResponse, wr.EndGetResponse)()
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Subscribe(response =>
                    {
                        // do stuff with the response
                    },
                ex =>
                    {
                        //there has been an exception
                    });
```

For WPF/Silverlight applications the ObserveOnDispatcher marshalls the observer back to the UI thread, there is a specific scheduler available for winforms if that's your weapon of choice.

If you want to cancel before the request returns, just dispose of the IDisposable that is returned from the subscribe call.

Rx takes some time to get your head around, but it's very powerful once you do. (I don't  understand all of it yet either)

Edit - here is some code I threw together in a winforms app that reads the response from google.com, using Rx:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

        Observable
            .FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(req.BeginGetResponse, req.EndGetResponse)()
            .ObserveOn(this)
            .Subscribe(r =>
                            {
                                using (var s = r.GetResponseStream())
                                using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
                                {
                                    textBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                }
                            },
                        ex =>
                            {
                                textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
                            });
    }
}
```

The form has a text box on it and it will update the text with either the response or the exception message...

The ObserveOn call handles all the Control.Invoke stuff for you and makes sure the code that is run on subscription is on the correct UI thread.

Just use nuget to install the 'Rx-WinForms' package for all the right references :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what .net framework you are on, Async is going to be very easy in the upcoming release of c#,

please try  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx

Comment: Currently using .NET 4.0, It does indeed look much easier. Though there must be a more common solution as to  this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your code on your Form you can just do a simple

```
private void EventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(EventMethod), sender, e);
        return;
    }
    //cast your args to the type you know them to be
    //do stuff with e or sender 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Drop a timer control onto your form and in the tick call this:

```
public void AsynchFetchIntoListBox(ListBox listBox)
        {
            var wr = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.org");
            IAsyncResult ar = null;
            ar = wr.BeginGetResponse(_ =>
                {
                    var r = wr.EndGetResponse(ar);
                    using (var s = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var result = s.ReadToEnd();
                        listBox.Invoke((Action)(() => 
                            listBox.Items.Add(result)));
                    }
                } , null);
        }
```

This just fetches the raw html of example.org into a listbox but it could be any asynch query updating any control in basically the same fashion.